# Typo3: capture default generated css in lib

Tags: css, typo3, default

I need to capture the default generated CSS inside a lib, which will be displayed in an XML page type.
For this, I tried:

```
lib.defaultCss = COA
lib.defaultCss {
  10 < plugin.tx_cssstyledcontent._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE
  wrap = <defaultCss><![CDATA[|]]></defaultCss>
}

page.1 < lib.defaultCss
```

In the object browser I can see the correct value (default css generated by css_styled_content extension), but on page, I only get the empty `<defaultCss>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `_CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE` is a property, not an object.

Try this instead:

```
lib.defaultCss = COA
lib.defaultCss {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value < plugin.tx_cssstyledcontent._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE
  wrap = <defaultCss><![CDATA[|]]></defaultCss>
}

page.1 < lib.defaultCss
```